# Streaming H264 video for Logitech C920 using GStreamer produces a relief

Tags: gstreamer, h.264

I'm trying to stream the native H264 video from a Logitech C920 camera using GStreamer 1.2.4:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! video/x-h264,width=640,height=480,framerate=10/1 ! \
h264parse ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! ximagesink sync=false
```

This produces an image output which is a kind of a relief:
[image: Relief image of Logitech C920 H264 stream]

As soon as add more movement to the scene, the image quality improves but is still far away from being sufficent. I seems that anyhow the stable parts of the video stream are not decoded.

Any ideas?

I'm using gstreamer 1.2.4 on a Banana PI (Debian Wheezy)

Comment: What's happening is you're receiving P-frames that are being decoded without a reference IDR frame.  If you wait long enough, or move enough, do you eventually get a good frame, and the stream afterwards seems fine?

Comment: Also if you're not going to do anything with the h264 packets (you just want the raw image data), try using a different caps.  video/x-raw instead of video/x-264.